# How can I change the page color using radio buttons and Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I want to make an option to change the page color using radio buttons with vuejs

So far I have this

JavaScript

```js
var theme = new Vue({
    el: '#theme',
    data: {
        picked: ''
    }
})
```

HTML

```html
<div id="theme">
<span>Chose the color theme you want</span>        
<br>   
<input type="radio" id="dark" value="Dark" v-model="picked">
<label for="dark">Dark</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" id="light" value="Light" v-model="picked">
<label for="light">Light</label>
<br>
<span>Picked: {{ picked }}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine [watch](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) and [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties).

```js
var theme = new Vue({
  el: '#theme',
  data: {
    picked: ''
  },
  watch: {
    picked: function(val) {

      if (val == 'Dark') {
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--bg", "#000");
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--color", "#fff");
      } else if (val == 'Light') {
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--bg", "#fff");
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--color", "#000");
      }

    },
  }
})
```

```css
html {
  --bg: pink;
  --color: #000;
}

body {
  background: var(--bg);
  color: var(--color);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="theme">
  <span>Chose the color theme you want</span>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" id="dark" value="Dark" v-model="picked">
  <label for="dark">Dark</label>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" id="light" value="Light" v-model="picked">
  <label for="light">Light</label>
  <br>
  <span>Picked: {{ picked }}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [class binding](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) with the `picked` value

```js
var theme = new Vue({
  el: '#theme',
  data: () => ({ picked: 'Light' })
})
```

```css
html,
body,
#theme {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#theme {
  transition: background .2s ease,
              color .2s ease;
}

.theme-Dark {
  background-color: #002b36;
  color: #839496;
}

.theme-Light {
  background-color: #fdf6e3;
  color: #657b83;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="theme" :class="`theme-${picked}`"> <!--  class binding here -->
  <span>Chose the color theme you want</span>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" id="dark" value="Dark" v-model="picked">
  <label for="dark">Dark</label>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" id="light" value="Light" v-model="picked">
  <label for="light">Light</label>
  <br>
  <span>Picked: {{ picked }}</span>
</div>
```